# SQL and CARTO - Dot Density Visualization

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto

I need help with running a SQL on CARTO.

I want to generate a dot density similar to the link [here](https://carto.com/blog/dot-density-map-finger-painting/).

The second portion of the SQL code deletes the `cartodb` column and nothing changes on the map.

```
SELECT 
  ST_TRANSFORM(cynthia.by_state_population(the_geom,DP0080005/100),3857) as the_geom_webmercator, 
  'DP0080005' as ethnicity, 
  1 as t from tract_2010census_dp1_simple
```

[image: Table from SHP File]

[image: CARTODB Error Code]

Answer (score 1):

The blog you have based your query uses Editor, the old CARTO UI. If you are using Builder, you will need to add `the_geom` and `cartodb_id` to your `SELECT` statement to make it work.